# cover pageReference method in test class

Tags: unit-test, pagereference

this is class code

```
public pagereference RedirectToPrePopulatedLeadPage() {

    PageReference editList = new PageReference(LABEL.SFA_NEW_LEAD_RET_URL);
    editList.getParameters().put(LABEL.SFA_NEW_LEAD_COMPANY_FIELD_ID,LABEL.SFA_NEW_LEAD_COMPANY_DEFAULT);
    editList.getParameters().put(LABEL.SFA_NEW_LEAD_LAST_NAME_FIELD_ID,LABEL.SFA_NEW_LEAD_LAST_NAME_DEFAULT);

    if(!ProfileNameIdMap.isEmpty() && ProfileNameIdMap.containsKey(UserInfo.getProfileId())){            
        if(ProfileNameIdMap.get(UserInfo.getProfileId()).Name == LQTLPROFILE){
            editList.getParameters().put(LABEL.SFA_NEW_LEAD_STATUS_FIELD,LABEL.LQTL_WORKING);
            system.debug(editList.getParameters().get(LABEL.SFA_NEW_LEAD_STATUS_FIELD));
        }
        else if(ProfileNameIdMap.get(UserInfo.getProfileId()).Name == LQTTPROFILE){
            editList.getParameters().put(LABEL.SFA_NEW_LEAD_STATUS_FIELD,LABEL.LQTT_WORKING);
        }
    }
    if(String.isNotBlank(accId)){
        editList.getParameters().put(LABEL.SFA_NEW_LEAD_ACC_FIELD_LKID,accId);
        editList.getParameters().put(LABEL.SFA_NEW_LEAD_ACC_NAME_ID,accName);    
    }
    editList.setRedirect(true);
    return editList;

}
```

how to cover this block in test class
i have created

```
pageReference pg = myclassname.RedirectToPrePopulatedLeadPage();
```

but its not working and giving an error message

Comment: you would need to prepare appropriate data in your test class before calling the RedirectToPrePopulatedLeadPage method, such that it will cover scenarios.

Comment: That seems like a somewhat excessive use of capitalization.